# How to transfer questions / answers pairs into a view-class in the playframework?

Tags: java, scala, data-structures, playframework, scala-template

I am trying to fake some question / answer pairs in my controller-class and send them into the view-class via using the playframework.

I have the following structure for questions / answers:

```
- Question 1
-- Answer 1.1
-- Answer 1.2

- Question 2
-- Answer 2.1

- Question 3
-- Answer 3.1
-- Answer 3.2
...
```

I have those in my Application.java class. For the moment they are hardcoded in, later I want to use a database.

Then I have a index.scala.html (the view class), in there I iterate over the questions and answers and show them like in my structure - which does not work!

But how can I send them from the java class to the scala class?

So far I have tried using a Google Guava Multimap:

```
// Needed, as the view-class gets a List[String]
static List<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> answerList = new ArrayList<String>();

// Create the Multimap, one for questions, one for answers
    Multimap<String, String> questionMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    Multimap<String, String> answerMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

// Question 1, in the format Questiontext (used as key here) / ID, votescore, Userid
    questionMap.put("What happens if I use a break here?", "e77dccbc-fd8d-4641-b9ca-17528e5d56b2");
    questionMap.put("What happens if I use a break here?", "150");
    questionMap.put("What happens if I use a break here?", "345");

    // Answer 1.1 in the format: Answertext / ID / Question-ID (Answer needs to be linked to a question) / votescore / Userid
    answerMap.put("The loop will just fall through!", "b8756ff5-ff8a-4a17-9517-811b91639fdf");
    answerMap.put("The loop will just fall through!", "e77dccbc-fd8d-4641-b9ca-17528e5d56b2");
    answerMap.put("The loop will just fall through!", "46");
    answerMap.put("The loop will just fall through!", "567");

// The Lists get the keySets (contains the questiontext / answertext)
    questionList.addAll(questionMap.keySet());
    answerList.addAll(answerMap.keySet());

// returns the 2 lists to the view-class
public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render(questionList, answerList));
}
```

index.scala.html:

```
// first line, gets the q/a lists as parameters
@(questions: List[String], answers: List[String])

// iterate over the question-list and show the questiontext (works)

@for(index <- 0 until questions.size){
    @questions(index)

// iterate over the answers and show them as well, I know I am iterating wrong somehow here!
@for(index <- 0 until answers.size){
    @answers(index)
}
```

I know I am iterating wrongly over the answers, so the structure shown now is:

```
- Question 1
-- Answer 1.1
-- Answer 1.2
-- Answer 2.1
-- Answer 3.1
-- Answer 3.2

- Question 2
-- Answer 1.1
-- Answer 1.2
-- Answer 2.1
-- Answer 3.1
-- Answer 3.2

- Question 3
-- Answer 1.1
-- Answer 1.2
-- Answer 2.1
-- Answer 3.1
-- Answer 3.2
...
```

So I am showing every answer in every question. This stems from the problem that I dont know how to link the answers to the corresponding question! I have IDs in the questions and answers, but I dont know how I can get those (together with the q/a text!) into the view class and how to iterate over the IDs.

Maybe I can use another data-structure that makes my approach easier?

**[EDIT1]====================================================[EDIT1]**

I have changed my approach now and use a normal Map with 2 classes (Question.java and Answer.java):

Question.java (Answer.java is similar):

```
public class Question {

public String ID;
public String questionText;
public Integer voteScore;
public String userID;

public Question(String inputID, String inputQuestionText, Integer inputVoteScore, String inputUserID){
    this.ID = inputID;
    this.questionText = inputQuestionText;
    this.voteScore = inputVoteScore;
    this.userID = inputUserID;
}
}
```

In my Application.java (Controller class) I use a Map and have some fake questions / answers:

```
static Map<Question, List<Answer>> myMap = new HashMap<Question, List<Answer>>();

Question question1 = new Question("xyz", "Do Androids dream?", 127, "Marcus");
Answer answer11 = new Answer("zab", "xyz", "Only of electric sheep!", 70, "Tibor");
Answer answer12 = new Answer("qwert", "xyz", "No, they dont!", 10, "Sarah");

Question question2 = new Question("fgh", "Why is the sky blue?", 76, "Frank");
Answer answer21 = new Answer("xcv", "fgh", "Frequency filtered sunlight!", 45, "Oliver");
Answer answer22 = new Answer("tzu", "fgh", "Light reflects from the blue sea water!", 3, "Tom");

List<Answer> answerList1 = new ArrayList<Answer>();
answerList1.add(answer11);
answerList1.add(answer12);

List<Answer> answerList2 = new ArrayList<Answer>();
answerList2.add(answer21);
answerList2.add(answer22);

myMap.put(question1, answerList1);
myMap.put(question2, answerList2);

return ok(views.html.index.render(myMap));
```

In my index.scala.html:

```
@import model.Question
@import model.Answer

@(myMap: Map[Question, List[Answer]])

@for((key, value) <- myMap){
  @key.questionText - @value <br>
}
```

The output is now:

```
Why is the sky blue? - 
[ID = xcv questionID = fgh answerText = Frequency filtered sunlight! voteScore = 45 userID = Oliver, ID = tzu questionID = fgh answerText = Light reflects from the blue sea water! voteScore = 3 userID = Tom]

Do Androids dream? - 
[ID = zab questionID = xyz answerText = Only of electric sheep! voteScore = 70 userID = Tibor, ID = qwert questionID = xyz answerText = No, they dont! voteScore = 10 userID = Sarah]
```

So how do I iterate over the answerTexts and show them in my view-class? I dont know how to access into the list.

Comment: Why not create `Question` and `Answer` classes with the required fields for each item and then use a `Map<Question, List<Answer>>`?

Comment: Hey Salem, I have changed my approach now and use a Question / Answer class. Please see my Edit1 in my Post. I seem to be close to the solution, but I'm stuck with the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an inner loop to iterate over the answers (because the *value* variable will hold the answers to the question of the loop iteration):

**index.scala.html**

```
@import model.Question
@import model.Answer

@(myMap: Map[Question, List[Answer]])

@for((key, value) <- myMap){
  @key.questionText<br>
  @for(ans <- value){
     <p>Possible answer: @ans.answerText</p>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had found a solution also:
`@for((key, value) <- myMap){
   @key.questionText <br>
   
   @value.map { e =>
      @e.answerText <br>
     }
     <br>
 }` ... but yours feels more natural.

Comment: @hamena314 funny because I actually wanted to use `map` in my answer but saw that you are using `for` in your code. At this point I am actually more the fan of `map` - it relates a bit more to this functional approach and am I sure it will feel "natural" to you after some time, too